# Focus set automatically on Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, windows-ce

I have a form which contains some textBoxes. I have configured the textBox's GotFocus and LostFocus events.

**My problem** is: When some textBox loses focus, the form automatically set the focus on the first textBox and it triggers the GotFocus event again.

`How do I not set the focus by default?`

Comment: Check the tabindex of the text boxex from where focus is transferred to first text box. I think the TabStop property is set to false for the textboxes for some of the controls.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the focus with javascript on the window help?

Comment: @ub1k We are working with winforms and windows-ce. I doubt he is using javascript.

Comment: I think that one of worst design decision made by Microsoft is the Focus/LostFocus pair. Try to avoid to mess with these events.

Comment: @Romil your suggestion works fine! Please put your suggestion as an answer and I will select it to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the tabindex of the text boxex from where focus is transferred to first text box. 
I think the TabStop property is set to false for the textboxes for some of the controls.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I change the tabIndex and set the tabStop to false and it works ok now.